# Enable S3 webpages to redirect with query parameters

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-api-gateway, query-string

Is there a way to make S3 hosted static webpages to get redirected urls such as `.amazonaws.com/recipe.html?id=293842`?

I want to redirect a button on `index.html` when clicked, redirect to `recipe.html` with query parameters in it.

Comment: I think this needs clarification. Are you saying that you have a button on `index.html` that you would like to navigate to `recipe.html`?

Comment: have a button on ```index.html``` navigate to ```recipe.html```, yes.

Comment: Why can't this be achieved with an `<a>` tag?

Comment: why it can be just doing `<a href="recipe.html?id=293842">Click Here </a>`  ? is issue here ? it should not be S3 issue

Comment: Just found out that putting a parameter on the link does not call error. Thank you!